# How to crop image around box in python openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a program to crop a image around a rectangle in OpenCV. How could I go about doing this. I also need it to be able to turn multiple rectangles into cropped images.

I've tried using this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/, but I dont know how to get the borders of the shape and crop around it.

I hope to get an output of multiple images, that have pictures of the contents of the triangle.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you attach sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Reece365, I had the same problem for my own project, so I've shared my solution, hopefully it helps you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just recently done this for one of my projects, and it worked perfectly.

Here is the technique I use to implement this in Python OpenCV:

- Display the image using OpenCV's `cv2.imshow()` function.
- Select 2 points (x, y) on an image. This can be done by capturing mouse click events with OpenCV. One way to do this is to click with your mouse where the first point is, while still clicking move towards the second points, and let go from the mouse click once the cursor is over the correct point. This selects the 2 points for you. In OpenCV, you can do this with `cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN` and `cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP`. You can write a function to record the two points using the mouse capture events and pass it to `cv2.setMouseCallback()`.
- Once you have your 2 coordinates, you can draw a rectangle using OpenCV's `cv2.rectangle()` function, where you can pass the image, the 2 points and additional parameters such as the colour of the rectangle to draw.
- Once you're happy with those results, you can crop the results using something like this:

```
image = cv2.imread("path_to_image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", your_callback_function)
cropped_img = image[points[0][1]:points[1][1], points[0][0]:points[1][0]]
cv2.imshow("Cropped Image", cropped_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is one of the results I get on one of my images.

**Before (original image)**:
[image: before]

**Region of interest selected with a rectangle drawn around it**:
[image: roi selected]

**After (cropped image)**:
[image: after]

I started by following this excellent tutorial on how to implement it before further improving it on my own, so you can get started here: [Capturing mouse click events with Python and OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/). You should also read the comments at the bottom of the attached tutorial to easily improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get co-ordinates of box using 'BoundedRect' function. Then use slicing operation, to extract required part of image.